# Merging pandas dataframes generated by for loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let say I have below code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random
import string

data = ['DF1', 'DF2', 'DF2']

for i in data :
    DF = pd.DataFrame([random.choices(string.ascii_lowercase,k=5), [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]]).T
    DF.columns = ['col1', 'col2']
    DF['i'] = i
```

So for each `i`, I have different `DF`. Finally I need to merge all those data frames based on `col1` and add numbers in `col2` row-wise.

In this case, total number of such dataframes is based on length of `data` array, and therefore variable. In `R` we can use `do.call()` function to merge such varying number of data frames. In `Python` is there any way to achieve this?

For example, lets say we have 3 individual tables as below:

[image]
[image]
[image]

After joining based on `col1`, I expect below table (sorted based on `col1`)

[image]

Any pointer will be highly appreciated.

Comment: "Finally I need to merge all those data frames based on col1 and add numbers in col2 row-wise." How? Please explain more or show a basic implementation. Otherwise, you can just stack all dataframes, if there is no condition.

Comment: For equal type of dataframes (equal columns), you can just collect the individual dataframes in a list, then use `pd.concat(dataframe_list)`.

Comment: @9769953 I have added information on the resulting table in my original post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, try:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[*'adrtg']
                   ,'col2':[10,11,12,13,14]
                   ,'data':['DF1']*5})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[*'adspq']
                   ,'col2':[10,11,12,13,14]
                   ,'data':['DF2']*5})
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[*'dcxyz']
                   ,'col2':[10,11,12,13,14]
                   ,'data':['DF3']*5})

pd.concat([df1, df2, df3]).groupby('col1', as_index=False)['col2'].sum()
```

Output:

```
   col1  col2
0     a    20
1     c    11
2     d    32
3     g    14
4     p    13
5     q    14
6     r    12
7     s    12
8     t    13
9     x    12
10    y    13
11    z    14
```

Comment: Thanks. This is the expected result, however the number of original matrices is variable to me. In the present case, it is `3` but in the real case, it could be any number based on the length of `data`. How can I change `pd.concat([df1, df2, df3])` to make the length variable?

Comment: Are the real number of dataframes in a list or dictionary?  You can use list comprehension inside pd.concat.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `merge` and actually you will be `cross join`ing the dataframes :

```
import pandas as pd
import random
import string

data = ['DF1', 'DF2', 'DF2']
df = pd.DataFrame([random.choices(string.ascii_lowercase,k=5), [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]], ).T
df.columns = ['col1', 'col2']
da = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['data'])
res = df.merge(da, how='cross')

print(res)
```

output:

```
>>>   
    col1 col2 data
0     j   10  DF1
1     j   10  DF2
2     j   10  DF2
3     d   11  DF1
4     d   11  DF2
5     d   11  DF2
6     k   12  DF1
7     k   12  DF2
8     k   12  DF2
9     e   13  DF1
10    e   13  DF2
11    e   13  DF2
12    n   14  DF1
13    n   14  DF2
14    n   14  DF2

Process finished with exit code 0
```